# How to assign a value to nested list while keeping the original list in python

Tags: python

I am having two strange problems with python.

First of all, when I assign a value to a nested list like `foo[0][0] = 1`, `foo` is changed to `[[1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0]]`.

Secondly, even when I use `.copy()`, it assigns the same thing to the original value.

```py
>>> foo = [[0]*3]*3
>>> bar = foo.copy()
>>> bar[0][0] = 1
>>> bar
[[1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0]]
>>> foo
[[1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0]]
```

I need `bar` to be changed to `[[1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]` instead, and for `foo` to stay the same.

How can I do this?

Comment: Instead of `bar = foo.copy()` write `bar=foo[:]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use deepcopy instead, and don't initialise your lists with `[[x]*n]*n`:

```
import copy
foo = [[0 for _ in range(3)] for _ in range(3)]
bar = copy.deepcopy(foo)
bar[0][0] = 1
print(foo)
print(bar)
```

Output:

```
[[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]
[[1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]
```

Comment: Note the output of `bar` this still suffers from the original issue of how `foo` was initialized

Comment: It still answers the second part of the question, and I've changed it